# How to remove breadcrumbs from homepage

Tags: php, magento

When Full Page Cache is on the breadcrumbs show up on the home page,

i've tried changing the line `<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>` to `<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs) && !$this->getIsHomePage()): ?>` in \app\design\frontend\enterprise\[THEME]\template\page\html\breadcrumbs.phtml yet it still shows up

i've tried adding `<remove name="breadcrumbs" />` to the "Layout Update XML" of the CMS page which is the homepage yet it still shows up

I've tried putting in `Mage::log()` or a `<p>` before the if statement however it works on every other page but the home page

a google search gives me nothing that i don't know (the Layout Update XML thing i got from one site) and most results are asking how to add the breadcrumbs when i search for "how to remove breadcrumbs from homepage

i'm wondering if there is any other way to remove the breadcrumbs from the homepage which i may have yet tried

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the code from your second paragraph but changing `!$this->getIsHomePage()` to

```
!Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()
```

If that doesn't work (depends on your version of Magento: you should find the function `getIsHomePage` defined in ./code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php), then you can use the following instead.

```
$this->getUrl('') !== $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true))
```

Comment: nope, didn't work, i checked app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php and found `getIsHomePage()`, i refreshed the cache, deleted everything in var/cache and even cleared by browser cache, reload the home page to see the breadcrumbs are gone but when i go into a category and return to the homepage it's back again with what the breadcrumbs were on the previous page

Comment: Ah, by "the breadcrumbs" you mean "some breadcrumbs from a previous page"?  If that's the case and it's truly a cacheing issue then I can only wish you luck.  I'll delete my above answer if you edit your question to (a) make it clearer what you mean by "the breadcrumbs", and (b) replace `!$this->getIsHomePage()` by `!Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()` (the former will always evaluate to `true` in this context).